# Unable to Match user and pass Login form netbeans

Tags: java, database, netbeans, authentication

how can I match user and password in the conditions below. I am always getting UserName/Password does not match.

```
try
{
    Conn();
    st = conn.createStatement();
    rs = st.executeQuery("Select UserName,PassWord from login_tbl where UserName = '"+txtUser.getText()+"' and PassWord = '"+txtPass.getPassword()+"'");

    if(rs != null)
    {
        new CarRent().setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Username or Password is incorrect","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }
}
```

Comment: please use PreparedStatement. Your code can leads to sql injection attacks. Furthermore are you sure you have no uppercase lowercase issue?

Comment: Have you run this query directly in the database ?

Comment: I mean run your query directly in the database you are using like oracle, mysql window.

Comment: no error with the query sir. the problem is how do i compare my user and pass fields with the database value

Comment: Does this shows the `UserName,PassWord` values in the database editor ?

Comment: yes sir...............

Answer (score 0):

You should use this `rs.next()` instead of this `rs != null`

```
try
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Username is : " + txtUser.getText().trim().toString() + " Password is : " + txtPass.getPassword().trim().toString(),"",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        Conn();
        st = conn.createStatement();
        rs = st.executeQuery("Select UserName,PassWord from login_tbl where UserName = '"+txtUser.getText()+"' and PassWord = '"+txtPass.getPassword()+"'");


        if(rs.next())
        {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password is valid","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            new CarRent().setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();

         }

        else
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your Username or Password is incorrect","",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

        }
```

Comment: Shivastava - the pass and user is always wrong even it is not

Comment: It seems that problem is not here but any other side!! Are you sure you are getting values in your `txtUser.getText()` & `txtPass.getPassword()` are getting values from your text boxes. Check if there are not any space present in the username & the password field. Again updated the code. Run it & tell how many popup occurs & what is written on them!!!

Answer (score 0):

i already solved my problem thanks to all :)

```
String sql = "select * from login_tbl where usern=? and pass=?";
   try{

       Conn();
   ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   ps.setString(1,txtUser.getText());
   ps.setString(2,new String(txtPass.getText()));
   rs=ps.executeQuery();
   if (rs.next()){
       //about s= new about();
       //
       //s.setVisible(true);
       new CarRent().setVisible(true);
       dispose();
      }
   else

   {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Password or Username is incorrect");
   }
   }
   catch(Exception e)
   {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);

   }
```